# How to manipulate one column of a table using the value in another column

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Let's imagine I have the following table structure

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

and I want to transform it into the following table

```
dataEdited = {{a, (f[a] + f[b])/f[a]}, {c, (f[c] + f[d])/f[c]}, ...}
```

by leaving the first column unchanged and applying a function to the second column which also involves the first column.

My attempt is to apply MapAt to the second column, but I don't know how I can access the first column in this way. In the small example below I just apply the sine function to the second column.

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
dataEdited = Transpose[MapAt[Sin /@ #1 &, Transpose[data], 2]];
```

Any ideas or "best practice" recommendations how to handle this kind of operations?

Comment: data /. {a_, b_} :> {a, (f[a] + f[b])/f[a]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the solutions that @kguler present. Here is another solution (please tell me if there is a drawback with this):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
dataEdited = data /. {a_, b_} -> {a, (f[a] + f[b])/f[a]}
```

> {{a, (f[a] + f[b])/f[a]}, {c, (f[c] + f[d])/f[c]}, {e, (f[e] + f[f])/
>     f[e]}}

Edit: I see that @alancalvitti already showed this (but with `:>` instead of `->`). Sorry, not my meaning to steal your answer.

Comment: thank you, very nice and easily readable code :-)
is there any disadvantage to the examples given by kguler?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

ClearAll[foo, f1, f2, f3];
f1 = MapAt[Divide[Plus @@ foo /@ {##}, foo@#] & @@ # &,Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], #}], {{All, 2}}] &;
f2 = MapAt[Divide[Plus@##, #] &@@ # &, Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], Map[foo, #, {-1}]}], {{All, 2}}] &;
f3 = {#1, (foo[#] + foo[#2])/foo[#]} & @@@ # &;

f1 @ data == f2 @ data ==f3 @ data
(* True *)

f1 @ data
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
transform[{x_, y_}] := {x, (f[x] + f[y])/f[x]}
```

then

```
transform/@data
```

[image]